# Is there anything like OGC Property IN list Filter?

Tags: geoserver, ogc

I am converting some CQL filters to OGC, and I'm wondering whether there is something like a   propery in list filter in OGC, or the only solution is to combine the PropertyIsEqualTo with an OR filter. I suspect there isn't, but if you have a nicer solution please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the definitive answer from the OGC standards. Current Feature Encoding standard 2.0 is at http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/09-026r2/09-026r2.html and I fear that you are right. There is an example (number 12) in the standard about this (

```
<fes:Or>
         <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <fes:ValueReference>FIELD1</fes:ValueReference>
            <fes:Literal>10</fes:Literal>
         </fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
         <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <fes:ValueReference>FIELD1</fes:ValueReference>
            <fes:Literal>20</fes:Literal>
         </fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
</fes:Or>
```